# HTTParty read_nonblock connection reset by peer Errno::ECONNRESET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm a new Ruby developer. I would like to send some concurrent requests (maximum 3 requests) at same time to get data. I know there are a lot of Http libs in Ruby that support for sending request. In the end, I choose HTTParty, however, it comes to some error when I try to send request.

```
response_data = Http::SearchFlightService.search(url, options)
```

The url value:

```
http://booknow.jetstar.com/Search.aspx?culture=vi-VN
```

And value of options params:

```
{:body=>{"search-origin01"=>"", "search-destination01"=>"", "ControlGroupSearchView$ButtonSubmit"=>"", "__VIEWSTATE"=>"", "undefined"=>"", "children"=>"0", "infants"=>"0", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT"=>"0", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_CHD"=>"0", "datedepart-01"=>"19/06/2016", "datereturn-01"=>"20/06/2016", "adults"=>"1", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMarketDay1"=>"19", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_ADT"=>"1", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMarketDay2"=>"20", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMarketMonth1"=>"2016-06", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMarketMonth2"=>"2016-06", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin1"=>"SGN", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListFareTypes"=>"I", "_pe_39b5379c652b_9df496572198"=>"null", "travel-indicator"=>"on", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$RadioButtonMarketStructure"=>"RoundTrip", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination1"=>"HAN", "pageToken"=>"sLkmnwXwAsY=", "culture"=>"vi-VN", "locale"=>"vi-VN", "currencyPicker"=>"VND", "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListCurrency"=>"VND"}, :headers=>{"Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}
```

My Http::SearchFlightService

```
class Http::SearchFlightService
  include HTTParty
  ssl_version :SSLv3
  def self.search(url, options)
    post(url, options)
  end
end
```

It showed error

```
/Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:104:in `read'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:399:in `read'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:289:in `block in read_body_0'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:260:in `inflater'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:279:in `read_body_0'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:163:in `reading_body'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1420:in `block in transport_request'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from /Users/Dona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

httparty seems to have some bugs. Had same `Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer`. Fixed by replacing httparty call to `net/http`

```
require 'net/http'
JSON.parse Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
```